# Disabling the Magento Core Module CatalogInventory

Tags: magento-enterprise, inventory, ee-1.11

**Scenario:**

- We have a store that sells virtual products that basically never go out of stock.
- While we profiled the queries running on the category landing page we found that there a number of queries that deal with inventory.

  E.g SELECT `mag_cataloginventory_stock_status`.`product_id`, `mag_cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` FROM `mag_cataloginventory_stock_status` WHERE (product_id IN('5665', '5664', '5663', '5662', '5661', '5660', '5659', '5658', '5657', '5655', '5654', '5653', '5652', '5651', '5650', '5649', '5648', '5647', '5646', '5645', '5644', '5643', '5642', '5641', '5639', '5638', '5636', '5635', '5634', '5633', '5630', '5629', '5628', '5626', '5625', '5623',.. And so on)) AND (stock_id=1) AND (website_id=1)
- As we really do not have any concept of Stock (we have another flag to avoid display of the product) I wanted to simply git rid of any overhead this adds.

**Question:**

- Is it possible to disable the core module Mage_CatalogInventory, I did try this and it threw a Fatal error saying Mage_Checkout depends on this.
- Is there a graceful way to simply disable this module ?

Answer (score 2):

Under the system config you can set on a site level if the system should manage the stock level of products.

```
System -> Config -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options.
```

This is also an option on the product level under the inventory tab of the manage product section.

**EDIT**

The select you have noticed is being trigger as part of the call to addStockStatusToProducts in the CatalogInventory Observer. Sadly I am not sure currently why it is doing this even when the manage stock is set to no.

```
$stockStatuses = $this->_getResource()->getProductStatus($productIds, $websiteId, $stockId);
```

Comment: Thanks David.. While this definitely seems to be the right config to change, after doing this .. Clearing cache .. re-indexing .. I still see the same query getting fired. Any ideas ?

Comment: Interesting, is the product taking the inventory settings from the config also?

Comment: Could you check if it is the function addStockStatusToCollection in the CatalogInvetory observer that is doing this select?

Comment: When I go and check at the product level it already has the Manage Stock Option greyed out and "No" in the drop-down. Yes, I placed put a log in the observer you mentioned and its getiing there.

Comment: What are the product types? and is the flag $productCollection->hasFlag('require_stock_items') set?

Comment: All are virtual products and the Logging the $productCollection->hasFlag('require_stock_items')  value gives me blank.

Comment: any resolution to this?  would seem that if your not working with the inventory system you should be able to quicken your page renders by not having to deal with it.  I have the same issue, not virtual products, but ones that have managed stock set to no and never need any updates to stocks.